# Eclipse complie error

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have the following code to connect the sqlite database to the Android app,and the `public class TestAdapter` doesn't work. When I compile the app I receive the following error:

```
The public type TestAdapter must be definied "
```

**My Code**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.util.Log;

public class TestAdapter 
{
protected static final String TAG = "DataAdapter";

private final Context mContext;
private SQLiteDatabase mDb;
private DataBaseHelper mDbHelper;

public TestAdapter(Context context) 
{
    this.mContext = context;
    mDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(mContext);
}

public TestAdapter createDatabase() throws SQLException 
{
    try 
    {
        mDbHelper.createDataBase();
    } 
    catch (IOException mIOException) 
    {
        Log.e(TAG, mIOException.toString() + "  UnableToCreateDatabase");
        throw new Error("UnableToCreateDatabase");
    }
    return this;
}

public TestAdapter open() throws SQLException 
{
    try 
    {
        mDbHelper.openDataBase();
        mDbHelper.close();
        mDb = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    } 
    catch (SQLException mSQLException) 
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "open >>"+ mSQLException.toString());
        throw mSQLException;
    }
    return this;
}

public void close() 
{
    mDbHelper.close();
}

 public Cursor getTestData()
 {
     try
     {
         String sql ="SELECT * FROM myTable";

         Cursor mCur = mDb.rawQuery(sql, null);
         if (mCur!=null)
         {
            mCur.moveToNext();
         }
         return mCur;
     }
     catch (SQLException mSQLException) 
     {
         Log.e(TAG, "getTestData >>"+ mSQLException.toString());
         throw mSQLException;
     }
 }
 }

public class DataAdapter {

}
```

What should I do?Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

delete the `public` from

```
public class DataAdapter {

}
```